# puppeteer cannot process string functions; get ERR: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded; message

Tags: string, timeout, puppeteer

The following code works sometimes and sometime I get an error "ERR: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded"

it appears to depend on the type of string function and the site requested

tried all sorts of things all I get is inconsistency of results; i.e. sometime it works and sometimes not; sorry for not having more info

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => 
{
try{ 
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://www.google.com')
const html = await page.content();              
y1 = html.replace('"',"xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
y2 = y1.substr(1,15);
console.log('HTML:', y2);
}//try
catch (err) {console.log('ERR:', err.message);}         
})();//async
```

Comment: I have been successful scraping sites and storing results in MYSQL but I need to get rid of quotes single and double (or escape them \) before storing in MYSQL;  hence why I am  trying to get the string functions to work before storing in database

Comment: Not sure what quotes have to do with this. Navigation timeout is when puppeteer can't open the target site in time (by default 30 seconds). `it appears to depend on the type of string function and the site requested` - some words must be missing here, please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

by default each time a page navigate to an url (page.goto) it waits for the event 'load' to be fired and by default it waits 30000ms, if the event (load) is not fired the page throw: Timeout Exceeded

probably you are loading a heavy or slow page 
you should change timeout to a bigger value depending on how much time your page take to load you can do that

by setting global timeout value for the page :

```js
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(timeout)
//timeout => the time in milliseconds
```

Or setting the timout in the params of the function call

```js
await page.goto(url,{
    timeout: 60000 //timeout here is 60 seconds
})
//timeout => the time in milliseconds
```